# How to choose modulus value in Rabin-Karp algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, math, string-matching, rabin-karp

I have a question about choosing the *q* and *d* [in Rabin-Karp algorithm](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~kol/courses/6783-w12/scribe-rabin-karp.pdf) for searching strings. The algorithm uses the values *q* as modulus and *d* as hash function.

If I choose *q* as number of power 2 and d=q-1 or d=q+1

- How can these choices affect spurious hits?
- What patterns will be sure spurious hits in case d=q+1 and in case d=q-1?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what `q` and `d` represent.  Are these associated with the hash function?

Comment: I edit the question, tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X mod (2^n +1) can be described as alternating sum / difference e.g.

X= 0x11223344, n=8,  X mod 257 == 0x44 - 0x33 + 0x22 - 0x11 mod 257.
The problems here is that any repeating letter will cancel itself -- not very practical -- of course n doesn't have to be 8.

X mod (2^n -1) will be the *sum* of all n bit patterns, e.g.

X= 0x11223344, n=8,  X mod 255 ==( 0x44 + 0x33 +0x22 +0x11 ) mod 255

The problem here is that toggling bytes cancel themselves:
Hash('ab') = Hash('ba').